# OpenQuery SQL returns different results

Tags: sql, oracle, openquery

I have setup a view in an Oracle database that runs the code:

```
select *
from Availabilities
```

This returns the results

```
Roster | StartDate | EndDate
Avail  | 18/5/16   | 18/5/16
Train  | 19/5/16   | 19/5/16
Avail  | 20/5/16   | 30/5/16
```

these results are correct and are as expected, however...

I have linked the server that this view is on to an SQL server. From there I run an OpenQuery directly to the view that produced that results set on the linked server through the code:

```
select *
from OpenQuery(LinkedServer,'SELECT *
FROM REPORT_USR.AvailabilitiesView')
```

The results it returns have combined the first and the third results:

```
Roster | StartDate | EndDate
Train  | 18/5/16   | 30/5/16
Avail  | 19/5/16   | 19/5/16
```

Why would it do this?  Is there a way to stop it doing this?

Thanks

Comment: I assume that running `SELECT * FROM REPORT_USR.AvailabilitiesView` directly on the Oracle server returns all the rows - it's always good to double check and be absolutely certain.

Comment: yes it does.  It returns all the rows

Comment: That's weird. I suggest using various Oracle views (or maybe Toad) to capture the query that is being submitted to Toad.

Comment: Can you post the code of the view AvailabilitiesView. Also, check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32699299/using-openquery-with-an-oracle-database-to-query-a-date-range

Comment: create view AvailabilitiesView
AS
select *
from Availabilities

Comment: also tried the solution in that thread, alas... No dice!  Our DBA thinks we should try updating our version of SQL.  Will let you know the results

Answer (score 0):

Try disconnecting and re-connecting on both ends - to make sure one of your connections is not returning uncommitted data.

Comment: Sorry, no dice on that one