# SQL query date range in python

Tags: python, sql-server, t-sql

I was simply trying to query an `SQLServer` database in a specific date range. Somehow I just can't figure it out myself. Here is what I did:

```
    import pyodbc
    import pandas as pd
    con = pyodbc.connect("Driver={SQL Server}; Server=link")
    tab = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(aaa, 'SELECT * FROM bbb.ccc WHERE number like (''K12345%'')')",con)

    tab['DT']
    0    2015-09-17 08:51:41
    1    2015-09-17 09:14:09
    2    2015-09-17 09:15:03
    3    2015-09-24 15:20:55
    4    2015-09-24 15:23:47
    5    2015-10-02 08:49:59
    6    2015-10-30 14:08:40
    7    2015-10-30 14:13:38
    8    2015-11-03 14:30:06
    9    2015-11-03 14:30:22
    10   2015-11-04 07:14:40
    11   2015-11-04 10:43:51
    Name: DT, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Now I thought I should be able to select the records on the dates between `2015-09-18` and `2015-10-02` by using the following query. Somehow it failed with error

> DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql: SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(aaa, 'SELECT * FROM bbb.ccc WHERE DT between ''2015-09-18'' and ''2015-10-02''')".

Can someone help explain what I did wrong?

```
 tab2 = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(aaa, 'SELECT * FROM bbb.ccc `WHERE DT between ''2015-09-18'' and ''2015-10-02''')",con)`
```

Comment: A little more research found similar question here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32699299/using-openquery-with-an-oracle-database-to-query-a-date-range).

It simply needs conversion of the date format. The following code works for me now:
tab2 = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(aaa, 'SELECT * FROM bbb.ccc `WHERE DT between to_date(''18-Sep-2015'') and to_date(''02-Oct-2015'')')",con)`

Answer (score 1):

You should use [parameter binding](https://mkleehammer.github.io/pyodbc/#params):

```
tab2 = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM bbb.ccc WHERE DT between ? and ?", con, params=['2015-09-18', '2015-10-02'])
```

The `?` are placeholders for the values you are passing from the list. The number of `?`'s must match the number of items from your list.

And I'm not sure why you have a `SELECT *` wrapped in another `SELECT *` so I simplified with just the innermost select.

Comment: IF you think about it for a bit, it totally makes sense, right.  Good detective work.